# Print a json file in textView

Tags: android, json, textview, assets

Here my json file: settings.json (in assets folder):

```
{
  "settings": [
    {
      "level": "upper"
    }
  ]
}
```

I working in Android Studio. I print the upper word in a TextView from the json file, but this not working, my app is crashed. Ideas?
my code in java file:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ArrayList<String> level = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        try {

            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(loadJSONFromAsset());

            JSONArray userArray = obj.getJSONArray("settings");

            for (int i = 0; i < userArray.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject userDetail = userArray.getJSONObject(i);

                level.add(userDetail.getString("level"));
            }
            } catch(JSONException e){
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        textView.setText(level.get(0));

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    public String loadJSONFromAsset() {
        String json = null;
        try {
            InputStream is = getAssets().open("settings.json");

            int size = is.available();

            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];

            is.read(buffer);

            is.close();

            json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");


        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        return json;
    }
```

Thank you.
Android, json, source code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this will work for you,

Write Your `onCreate()` method like this,

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        try {

            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(loadJSONFromAsset());
            JSONArray userArray = obj.getJSONArray("settings");
            for (int i = 0; i < userArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject userDetail = userArray.getJSONObject(i);
                level.add(userDetail.getString("level"));
            }
            } catch(JSONException e){
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        textView.setText(level.get(0));
    }
```

set `setContentView()` method first then initialize your textview.In your code you accessing text view before layout initialized.

Answer (score 1):

And why the else working in the if function? The level's record is upper. Why not true the if?

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        try {
            // get JSONObject from JSON file
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(loadJSONFromAsset());
            // fetch JSONArray named users
            JSONArray userArray = obj.getJSONArray("settings");
            // implement for loop for getting users list data
            for (int i = 0; i < userArray.length(); i++) {
                // create a JSONObject for fetching single user data
                JSONObject userDetail = userArray.getJSONObject(i);
                // fetch email and name and store it in arraylist
                level.add(userDetail.getString("level"));
            }
            } catch(JSONException e){
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        if (level.get(0) == "upper") {
            textView.setText(level.get(0));
        } else {

        }
```